# A Bash script that output lines in the files including a word

Tags: bash, shell, sh, cat

If I write a `sh file`, the script input 3 arguments of a folder, type of file (for example `.txt`) and a word. I need to check if there are 3 arguments at least and if not printing a message and then read all the files in the folder name and print all the lines that contains the word of the type file.

For example I have `folder_name-->myScript.sh example.txt` and in the `example.txt` we have the text:

```
hello word  
hello everybody  
good bye
```

And when I'll run `"./example.sh folder_name hello txt"` will output:

```
hello world  
hello everybody
```

I try to write this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Checking number of arguments.
if test "$#" -lt 3 
then
    echo "no enough arguments"
else
    folder_name=${1}
    type_file=${2}
    word=${3}
    # Show file contents with the word 
    echo "Lines that contains the ${word}:"
    # cat "${}
```

I don't know how to use the cat to read all the files and check and then print.

Comment: `grep -w "$word" example.txt`

Comment: @anubhava How do you write this in the code?

Comment: just copy/paste given command below last `echo` line

Comment: This looks like a restatement of [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67518367/write-a-script-bash) (which is now closed). Note that it is generally better to edit a closed question to improve it, rather than to ask a new one, so that readers can see the old context. However, it is done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to print matching lines, use `grep`, not `cat`.

The wildcard `*."$type_file"` will match all the files with the given suffix.

So the command should be:

```
cd "$folder_name"
grep -F -w "$word" *."$type_file"
```

The `-F` option matches `$word` as a fixed string, not a regular expression. `-w` makes it match whole words, not part of a word.

If you don't want to see the filenames before all the matching lines, add the `-h` option.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Checking number of arguments.
if test "$#" -lt 3 
then
    echo "no enough arguments"
else
    folder_name=${1}
    type_file=${2}
    word=${3}
    # Show file contents with the word 
    echo "Lines that contains the ${word}:"
    cd "$folder_name"
    grep -F -w "$word" *."$type_file"
fi
```

Comment: In the last line you mean type_file or file_type?

Comment: `if test "$#" -lt 3; then echo "..." >&2; exit 1; fi`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I thought about suggesting that, but it's more of a style issue.